# Converting 10Mb Rdata file to PMML using r2PPML yeilds a 350Mb PMML file. How can I make it smaller?

Tags: python, r, random-forest, pmml, rdata

I have an RData file which is a random forest model it is 10Mb in size. I want to convert it into PMML but when using the R2PMML library this creates a 350Mb PMML file which is far to large to work with. Any idea how I can make it smaller ? I want to be able to then use the PMML in a python production environment so would need to file to be significantly smaller.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to rearrange decision tree data structures by specifying the `compact = TRUE` conversion option:

```
library("r2pmml")
library("randomForest")
iris.rf = randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris)
r2pmml(iris.rf, "RandomForestIris-compact.pmml", compact = TRUE)
```

However, the size of a PMML file in local filesystem is not a very good indicator about how much memory it would consume during runtime. Your 350 MB file probably fits into 50-75 MB of RAM, when loaded properly (eg. 100 MB of your file is whitespace characters).

Comment: Thanks using compact=True parameter has reduced the size by more than half but still is around 150Mb. Any idea how to reduce even further ?

Comment: See the remainder of my answer - the size of the PMML file in local filesystem is not a good measure of anything. If you want to compare RData and PMML file sizes, then you must compress the PMML file first - a 150 MB PMML file would be then in 5-15 MB in size as well, and your problem would be "solved".